# How to design flexible UI in ionic?

Tags: user-interface, ionic3

1. How to place the UI components exactly where ever we want? like a
   button to be put at certain (x,y) on the screen.
2. How to align components horizontally?
3. How to place one component, relative to
   another component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use ion-grid (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/) and ionic CSS Utilities (https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/) where it is possible for component placement.

In general, Ionic is using SASS (sass-lang.com) to define the style of your UI.

You have many options if you wish to overwrite these default style values:

- in /src/theme/variables.scss file your changes will be global
- in /src/app/your-component.scss file your changes will be visible only in your-component (start the scss file with the selector of your component)

In any specific case, I recommend to start with the default style, then see your UI in browser developer view, inspect the element you want to change, and find which style class is responsible for that property you want to change. Then search this class on ionic Github source (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic). You will see the SASS file setting the property for this class. Check the SASS file to find out which variables it is changing, then set set this variable in your variables.scss file for global changes, or your-component.scss file for component specific changes (for example: $refresher-icon-color:blue).

.